# Condition in Where Clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I filter columns in where condition based on valued passed.

Ex:

```
declare @number nvarchar(200)
set @number = '2ddafa3'
```

Here @number could be int or uniqueIdentifer

so in where clause how can i achieve something as below.

```
select * from IntegrationIDTransactions
where case ISNUMERIC(@number) 
            When 1  Then [TransactioniD] = @number
            else [TransactionDomainGuid] = @number
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
where @number = 
    case ISNUMERIC(@number) 
        when 1 then cast([TransactioniD] as varchar(200))
        else cast([TransactionDomainGuid] as varchar(200))
    end
```

Edited to add the cast. The cast has to be inside the CASE; SQL server requires that all paths of the case produce the same variable type.

Comment: Sorry still getting error: 
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Tried with:

declare @number nvarchar(200)
set @number = '5'

select * from IntegrationIDTransactions
where @number = case ISNUMERIC(@number) 
    when 1 Then [TransactioniD] 
    else [TransactionDomainGuid]
    end

Comment: Right, it takes the type of the first CASE branch and assumes all branches produce that type.  Edited the answer.  Remus Rusanu's answer would perform better by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid such constructs and instead have two queries, one for WHERE TransactionId and one for WHERE TransactionDomainGuid:

```
if ISNUMERIC(@number)
  select * from IntegrationIDTransactions
  where [TransactioniD] = @number
else 
  select * from IntegrationIDTransactions
  else [TransactionDomainGuid] = @number
```

Even better, have the client do the IF and call the appropriate query. Writing queries like the one in your example is a performance killer, the result is unsargable and creates usually the worst execution plan for *both* cases.

Comment: +1, this is the only correct approach here if performance is of any concern.